# How to loop this cryptography program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code, but I'm not sure how to make it loop, so that after you finish encoding or decoding it brings the menu back up. It's working well right now, just no idea how to loop it.

```
import string

key = "qetuoadgjlxvnw ryipsfhkzcbm"
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
abc_key = string.maketrans(abc, key)
key_abc = string.maketrans(key, abc)

def encode():
    """Encodes input text"""
    text = raw_input ("Please enter text to be encoded: ")
    text_lower = string.lower(text)
    text_lower;
    print text_lower.translate(abc_key);

def decode():
    """decyphers code"""
    code = raw_input ("Please enter code to be decyphered: ")
    code_lower = string.lower(code)
    code_lower;
    print code_lower.translate(key_abc);


# Welcome message
print "Welcome to Jake's Cryptography program!"

# Print menu
print "SECRET DECODER MENU"
print "0) Quit"
print "1) Encode"
print "2) Decode"

option = raw_input ("What do you want to do?")

if option == "0":
    print "Thank you for during secret spy stuff with me!"
elif option == "1":
    encode()
elif option == "2":
    decode()
else:
    print "Sorry, that is not an option."
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a [`while`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) statement. Something like this:

```
# Welcome message
print "Welcome to Jake's Cryptography program!"

# Print menu
while True:
    print "SECRET DECODER MENU"
    print "0) Quit"
    print "1) Encode"
    print "2) Decode"

    option = raw_input ("What do you want to do?")

    if option == "0":
        print "Thank you for during secret spy stuff with me!"
        break
    elif option == "1":
        encode()
    elif option == "2":
        decode()
    else:
        print "Sorry, that is not an option."
```

**Notice the `break` statement!**

The above will print the menu each time. If you just want to print the prompt, move the `while True:` line down after the menu (but before the `raw_input` line), and then fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Welcome message here

option = -1
while option != 0:
    # Print menu
    # Raw input for the next option
    # Processing of the options
```

Answer (score 0):

```
option = 13

while (int(option) > 0):

    option = raw_input ("What do you want to do?")

    if option == "0":
        print "Thank you for during secret spy stuff with me!"
        print "and good night"
    elif option == "1":
        encode()
    elif option == "2":
        decode()
    else:
        print "Sorry, that is not an option."
```